# How to install color themes onto Emacs 24.3?

Tags: 12.04, themes, emacs

I'm trying to install the [Oblivion](https://github.com/pomeo/oblivion-emacs) color theme into GNU Emacs 24.3.

I downloaded the repository as a .zip file then moved the zip folder into my `~/.emacs.d/color-theme/themes` directory. I'm pretty sure this is my load path.

When I open emacs and do `M-x` and type `load-file "~/.emacs.d/color-theme/themes/Oblivion-theme.el"`, it complains `[No match]`. Even when I type `load-file "~.ema` and try to use the SPACE-bar autocompletion, it still complains `[No match]`. I think it's not recognizing this load path?

Finally when I use the command `to add a single directory to the load-path:`

`M-x add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/color-theme/themes"` it says `[No match]`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not setting up your `default-directory` properly.

```
(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/lisp/"))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

In this example, *everything* in ~/.emacs.d/lisp/ **and its subdirectories** will be loaded at startup.